# Remove unwanted stuff in Contact Form 7 from function.php

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

For the people using contact form 7 for wordpress, it's knew that this plugin adds automatically some stuff in the output code.
The normal output looks like this:

```
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap">
<input type="text" name="" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">        
</span>
```

plus some tags, paragraphs ecc...
Is there a way to remove all the

```
<span>, <br>, <p>
```

from the output leaving only the input fields?
I need this to be done from function.php so i can safetly update the plugin in the future.